# Suppress output in R

Tags: r, sublimetext, sublimerepl

It's possible to suppress all the output but the cat/print/similar in an R console?

I'm using SublimeRepl for Sublime Text and I would love to suppress the echo when executing a line (something like the ";" in matlab/octave), but keeping the output from cat/print or similar commands for obvious reasons.

Any idea?

Comment: can you give some specific examples

Comment: Ehmmm, open an R console and write "x=1", then press enter and the line just above will say "x=1", that's what i want to supress. In matlab you just add a semicolon after the line -> "x=1;" and then the output is supressed, i'm looking for the same thing in R.

Comment: That's what I thought you meant. I don't even understand why that would be possible let alone desirable.. you want to type some code in the console, press enter, and have it disappear?

Comment: Yes..? Actually, it's EXACTLY what RStudio does or when you execute a file with rscript instead of using the console..

Answer (score 0):

There are a fair number of R functions that return values  by way of the `invisible` function. They will `cat` some limited set of values, but the returned object will be much larger. See for instance the code of `lm`:

```
> invisible(strsplit(as.character(35600), split="..$"))
> invisible(print(strsplit(as.character(35600), split="..$")))
[[1]]
[1] "356"
```

The R console works by default as a read-eval-print loop and you need to emulate the read and eval segments but then  invisibly return a value to the workspace. I thought you might need to need to rewrite the `readline` function to get console output blanked out out. And probably need to fiddle with the `stdin` and `stdout` connections as well. Section 1.6, "Autoprinting" of the R Internals document will be required reading. It made me wonder if you could recompile R with the `R_Visible` variable set to FALSE. That section says "actual autoprinting is done by PrintValueEnv in file `print.c`"